# Question isn't a duplicate

Tags: discussion

Basically, a question I answered was closed as a duplicate, but I don't think it was. In fact, given the amount of votes and views it's received, it seems to be pretty helpful.

The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011780/prevent-caching-in-asp-net-mvc/10011896#10011896).

Which has been flagged as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/asp-net-mvc-disable-browser-cache).

Now, the first one is actually about preventing jQuery caching, as well as prevent caching on the server. Also, the first one the OP asks for an attribute that he can decorate his controllers with to perform the action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Then vote to reopen it.  That's what that mechanism exists for.

You can also help out by editing the question to better clarify how it's different from the proposed duplicate, if the wording of the post is causing confusion as to how they are different, or if the important distinctions are in the comments.

Note that just because the question has a lot of votes and is helpful doesn't mean it's not a duplicate.

If the questions really are duplicates, but you simply want your answer to be more visible, instead of being on a closed question (not that there's really anything wrong with that to begin with; it's not like it's deleted), then you could flag the post and request that a moderator merge the questions.  This would put all of the answers into a single open question.

Comment: Fair point, I've edited the title to signify the difference in the actual body of the question and nominated it for re-opening.

Comment: Personally I don't see how the questions are different.  If you really think they're not the same I'd suggest making it much clearer for those questions.

Comment: Jquery caching is **completely** different to simply clearing the cache on the server, thus the second question doesn't satisfy that. Plus the OP wants it to happen when an action is executed (using an attribute), which can only be achieved using a derived attribute from an `ActionFilter`. Frankly, they're **drastically** different. Just because they have caching and MVC in the question somewhere, doesn't mean they're the same.

Comment: @mattytommo Neither question is related to a server side cache.  Both questions are about setting response settings on the server to indicate to the client that the response shouldn't be cached.  I don't see how whether the client is for a proper page load or an AJAX request is any different.  Would the browser not respect the nocache response property in either case?  If not, then yes, they're different questions.  The OP didn't say it *must* be done using an attribute; he just said he needed to prevent caching and wondered if an attribute was the appropriate solution.

Comment: I'm not sure, but to be on the safe side forcing non-caching on both ends is the best approach to be safe. It *must* be done in an attribute as he only wants it for specific actions (it's just coincidental he asked for one).

Comment: @mattytommo There you go; you've now clarified the difference.  One question is disabling client side caching for a whole site/page, another is just for one action and *not* for the whole page.  If the answers to that are different, then they're not duplicates.  Make *that* clearer in the question (just emphasize that point a bit more than it is currently) and it should help quite a bit.

Comment: Done, you think that's more clearer? I've tried to emphasise it a bit more.

Comment: @mattytommo The bold is perhaps a tad over the top, but yes, I think that adding the sentence makes it quite clear why these two posts aren't duplicates.

Comment: Removed the bold, thanks again.